# making a text document a numeric list

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I am trying to automatically make a big corpus into a numeric list. One number per line. For example I have the following data:

```
Df.txt = 

In the years thereafter, most of the Oil fields and platforms were named after pagan “gods”.
We love you Mr. Brown.
Chad has been awesome with the kids and holding down the fort while I work later than usual! The kids have been busy together playing Skylander on the XBox together, after Kyan cashed in his $$$ from his piggy bank. He wanted that game so bad and used his gift card from his birthday he has been saving and the money to get it (he never taps into that thing either, that is how we know he wanted it so bad). We made him count all of his money to make sure that he had enough! It was very cute to watch his reaction when he realized he did! He also does a very good job of letting Lola feel like she is playing too, by letting her switch out the characters! She loves it almost as much as him.
so anyways, i am going to share some home decor inspiration that i have been storing in my folder on the puter. i have all these amazing images stored away ready to come to life when we get our home.
With graduation season right around the corner, Nancy has whipped up a fun set to help you out with not only your graduation cards and gifts, but any occasion that brings on a change in one's life. I stamped the images in Memento Tuxedo Black and cut them out with circle Nestabilities. I embossed the kraft and red cardstock with TE's new Stars Impressions Plate, which is double sided and gives you 2 fantastic patterns. You can see how to use the Impressions Plates in this tutorial Taylor created. Just one pass through your die cut machine using the Embossing Pad Kit is all you need to do - super easy!
If you have an alternative argument, let's hear it! :)
```

First I read the text using the command `readLines`:

```
text <- readLines("Df.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Secondly I get all the text into lower letters and I remove unnecessary spacing:

```
## Lower cases input:
lower_text <- tolower(text)
## removing leading and trailing spaces:
Spaces_remove <- str_trim(lower_text)
```

From here on, I will like to assign each line a number e.g.:

```
"In the years thereafter, most of the Oil fields and platforms were named after pagan “gods”." = 1
"We love you Mr. Brown." = 2
...
"If you have an alternative argument, let's hear it! :)" = 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "assign it a number". Use a two column data frame?

Comment: Something like `setNames(txt, 1:length(txt))` or `as.list(txt)`?

Comment: I guess it will be as.list(txt). As you guys can see in the final code, each line has assigned a number. Cheers!

Comment: No R data structure looks like the last example block in your question. It's unlikely you want each line of text to be the key in the R equivalent of an associative array. What you want to do with this text after you've cleaned it up and line-identified it is going to be the key factor in determining the data structure you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already do kinda have numeric line # associations with the vector (it's indexed numerically), but…

```
text_input  <- 'In the years thereafter, most of the Oil fields and platforms were named after pagan “gods”.
We love you Mr. Brown.
Chad has been awesome with the kids and holding down the fort while I work later than usual! The kids have been busy together playing Skylander on the XBox together, after Kyan cashed in his $$$ from his piggy bank. He wanted that game so bad and used his gift card from his birthday he has been saving and the money to get it (he never taps into that thing either, that is how we know he wanted it so bad). We made him count all of his money to make sure that he had enough! It was very cute to watch his reaction when he realized he did! He also does a very good job of letting Lola feel like she is playing too, by letting her switch out the characters! She loves it almost as much as him.
so anyways, i am going to share some home decor inspiration that i have been storing in my folder on the puter. i have all these amazing images stored away ready to come to life when we get our home.
With graduation season right around the corner, Nancy has whipped up a fun set to help you out with not only your graduation cards and gifts, but any occasion that brings on a change in one\'s life. I stamped the images in Memento Tuxedo Black and cut them out with circle Nestabilities. I embossed the kraft and red cardstock with TE\'s new Stars Impressions Plate, which is double sided and gives you 2 fantastic patterns. You can see how to use the Impressions Plates in this tutorial Taylor created. Just one pass through your die cut machine using the Embossing Pad Kit is all you need to do - super easy!
If you have an alternative argument, let\'s hear it! :)'

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

textConnection(text_input) %>% 
  readLines(encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
  stri_trans_tolower() %>% 
  stri_trim() -> corpus

# data frame with explicit line # column
df <- data_frame(line_number=1:length(corpus), text=corpus)

# list with an explicit line number field
lst <- map(1:length(corpus), ~list(line_number=., text=corpus[.]))

# implicit list numeric ids
as.list(corpus)

# explicit list numeric id's (but they're really string keys)
setNames(as.list(corpus), 1:length(corpus))

# named vector
set_names(corpus, 1:length(corpus))
```

There are a *plethora* of R packages that significantly ease the burden of text processing/NLP ops. Doing this work outside of them is likely to be reinventing the wheel. The [CRAN NLP Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) lists many of them.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code and tips @hrbmstr, one last thing. I will like the object to be in class numeric and not a list. I am trying to feed it into a n-gram function for word prediction and only works with input as numeric. Cheers

Comment: Perhaps you should go back to your original question and put in _all_ the necessary info for folks to try to help you. What you just entered in your comment is unclear. What "prediction". What "numeric"? You _do_ know you can do `as.numeric(vector_of_characters)` and get numbers back, right? You haven't clearly articulated your need in any way whatsoever.